# How should I use Consumer object in oauth2 v.2 in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, api, oauth, consumer

I am trying to use Yelp's API using oauth2 package (version 2), the Python 3.4 (in Anaconda's Spyder) code is like:

```
consumer = oauth2.Consumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
```

and I get this error message:

> > > AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Consumer'

I'm guessing Consumer doesn't exist in this version of oauth2! 
Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: I had the same issue, you can install python 2.7 on the same anaconda using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem with default installation of oauth2 using `pip install oauth2`. Right now I tried it on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 on Anaconda, its not working. 
You can copy the code ( _ _ init _ _.py) from [here](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/__init__.py) into your _ _ init _ _.py file and restart your kernel.

Location of your _ _ init _ _ .py file can be found via

```
import oauth2 as oauth
print(oauth)
```

After restart, kernel may ask for libraries which can be found via `pip search <library_name>` and then doing the `pip install <library_name>`