# How do I make a clean install of Anaconda for Mac?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using Anaconda/Jupyter with Python 2.7. However, I need to upgrade to Python 3. I tried the advice in [How to install 2 Anacondas (Python 2.7 and 3.4) on Mac OS 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9) but that gave me a "Package missing" error, which I could not resolve. Also, on the conda site, they advice that one can do the following:

```
    conda install python=3.5
```

but this just shows me which specifications are in conflict. There are 8 of them, and it seems like a of work and potential for mishaps to try to resolve all of those, and instead, I would like to remove the current anaconda and do a clean install of it with Python 3.5. But I can't find any information on how to do that.

Comment: you don't have to update/reinstall anaconda. Creating a new python3 environment should do. See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment for pointers how to do that. Enviroments are completely isolated and thus can have different python versions.