# What's the best way to upgrade from python 2.7 to 3 on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I'm currently using Python 2.7 with Anaconda and am considering making the move to Python 3.

What's the easiest/best way to upgrade while ensuring that custom modules I've installed are installed?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules

Comment: There is no magic trick to installing Python. You install the new Python version and then install your packages. You can run it side by side with your old 2.7 if you want.

Comment: That would explain why I couldn't find an answer to the question with Google :) Thank you for your time.

Comment: I found this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9