# Numpy installation issues with Miniconda2

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, caffe, miniconda

I'm on a `windows 10` machine and trying to install `caffe` for deep learning. The installation [steps](https://github.com/microsoft/caffe) asked me to install `Miniconda`, so I did. I already had `Anaconda2` installed on my system.

Now when I try to build the solution (using `Visual Studio 2013`) for `caffe` I get the following error:

```
Error 232 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'numpy/arrayobject.h': No such file or directory C:\caffe-master\python\caffe\_caffe.cpp 10 1 pycaffe
```

This is because `Miniconda` doesn't have numpy installed on it, even though I installed it using the following command:

```
conda install --yes numpy scipy matplotlib scikit-image pip
```

But when I open the `Miniconda2` console and run `import numpy`, I get an error saying it is not installed.

So my question eventually is: How do I install `Numpy` and `Scipy` on `Miniconda2` when I already have `Anaconda2` installed on my system?

Step by step instructions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you sure that numpy being missing is what's causing the first error?  Have you checked if C:\caffe-master\python\caffe\_caffe.cpp exists?

Comment: Yes, I did check, and the file exists. The reason I know the error is related to `numpy` is because I googles the error and most people suggested that it may not be installed. Upon checking this in Miniconda, I also found that it wasn't installed.

Comment: Ah, I was mixed up, It's saying that 'numpy/arrayobject.h' doesn't exist.  I suspect that what you really want is just to use your base Anaconda2 installation instead of trying to use Miniconda, as Anaconda is, as far as I understand, a superset of Miniconda.  I don't think having two installs of Anaconda like you do is really how it's intended to be used.

Comment: If you really need to have multiple Anaconda setups going, look into [conda  environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html).  There's support for having multiple environments but only one installation of Anaconda.

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9