# How to install both anaconda2 and anaconda3 in the same directory

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install both anaconda 2 and 3 because i need to use the standard packages in both python2 and python3.

I have anaconda2 installed already and i tried using it to create a python3 environment.

`conda create --name py36 python=3.6`

`source activate py36`

However i realized it lacked all the basic packages like matplotlib, numpy etc.

So rather than manually installing them in the py36 environment, i thought of downloading anaconda3 as well.

But i ran into an issue downloading it into the same directory as anaconda2 because anaconda3 folder is also called the same name as anaconda2 folder which is **anaconda**.

> How do i rename the folder when downloading anaconda3?
>
> And will this affect which anaconda i call when i do `conda <some
>   command>?`

Answer (score 4):

There are many duplicates of this question, such as here: [How to install 2 Anacondas (Python 2.7 and 3.4) on Mac OS 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9)

And conda provides the answer here:
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#installing-a-different-version-of-python

But TL;DR is just add `anaconda`

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6 anaconda
```