# How to add an alias name for the default anaconda ？

Tags: anaconda, conda, environment

As the following picture shows, my default Anaconda environment(anaconda3)have no name.

What's more, I'd love to set the Anaconda3 as my default python environment.

I also find this in my ~/.bashrc document.

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/home/cine/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/cine/anaconda2/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/cine/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/cine/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/cine/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

How to do ？

[image]

Comment: You installed both Anaconda 2 and 3? That is not recommended.

Comment: Oh, Really? But how can I do the switch between the Python2 and python3

Comment: That's what Conda is for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-and-3-on-mac-os

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install 2 Anacondas (Python 2 and 3) on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-and-3-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to include `PATH` variable in the default `.rc file`. An easy fix is just to add

```
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

to your `~/.profile` file. Then source the file by running

```
source ~/.profile
```

in a terminal.

Verify that it works by running

```
which python
```

You should see `/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python`

Comment: Please see that figure, we have two environment name： base and py27_ENAS, but there is no name for third environment. And I have added my ~/.bashrc document for your consideration. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, you method works. But there is still a “(base)” on the terminal. do you know have to remove it ？ Thanks a lot

Comment: well its tricky because you don't have env name in the first place, but if you had then you could rename it, conda                                                                     
`create --name new_name --clone old_name`
`conda remove --name old_name --all`                                                                            **or its alias:**  `conda env remove --name old_name`

Comment: you are right. I also find this. It looks that there is no way to add a name to the default env. I will wait  several days