# Conda install Python 3.x and 2.7x on Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've worked on a program under Python 3.x environment and also under Conda.

Now, I need to work on another program that only works under Python 2.7x.

My Conda version on my Mac is conda 4.8.3. I have a Conda environment for the program under Python 3.x. I think that my Anaconda is built for Python 3.x.

My questions:

1. How to install Python 2.7x on a system that already have Python 3.x.?
2. How to switch back and forth two systems? Does that mean I need to create two virtual Conda environment for Python 2.7x and Python 3.x?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the program with `python2` instead of just `python`?

[EDIT]
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415581/13314450

Comment: I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-and-3-on-mac-os      Could it be the solution?

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang Yes, here is an answer from within that question that should help: I updated my answer to include it as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415581/13314450