# quotes in Windows environment variable value

Tags: batch-file, path, pipe, environment-variables

I'm trying to implement, in a Windows batch file, the logic "if `%MyBinaryDir%` is not already at the beginning of the system `%PATH%`, then put it there; if it's already there, do nothing".

I've got this:

```
@echo %PATH% | findstr /i /b /c:"%MyBinaryDir%;" > nul || set "PATH=%MyBinaryDir%;%PATH%
```

This has always worked pretty well, **until** I tried to deploy on someone's machine where for some unearthly reason the `%PATH%` variable contained an odd number of quote characters.

The problem boils down to this:

```
@set x="
@echo %x%
@echo %x% | more
```

The second line prints a single `"` character.  The third line is tripped up by the quote character and fails to pipe the `echo` output to the second binary (in my case `findstr`, but in this boiled-down example `more`) at all. Instead, it literally prints the characters:

```
" | more
```

So my questions are:

(Y) How do I safely pipe *any* arbitrary string into a second binary?

and/or

(X) Is there a way of conditionally-prepending directories to the system path that avoids this mess?

Comment: I guess one solution is to write a separate batch file called `echopath.bat` containing the single line `@echo %PATH%`,   and then invoke it as `@call echopath | findstr ...`    But I'd like to keep the solution all within one file if possible.

Comment: Does your application **require** the directory to be prepended? Could it simply be prepended if it isn't already in the path?

Comment: @Magoo "Could it simply be prepended if it isn't already in the path?"    Ah, after initial confusion, I get it. You mean "if it's *anywhere* in the path, not necessarily at the beginning".  No, it needs to be at the beginning.  The `%PATH%` might, and frequently does, contain multiple `C:\PythonXX` directories, and I want to ensure that my chosen one is promoted to the front and therefore guaranteed to be accessed when I type `python.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use delayed expansion to echo any variable content in a safe way.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set x="
echo !x!
echo !x! | more
echo !path! | more
```

And to be safe also with empty variables you could use `echo(`

```
echo(!path! | more
```

There is also a question about [pretty print/split the path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can work with this.  Ideally I wanted to remove my target directory or directories from the `%PATH%` if they're already there and *move* them to the front, but as your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/3019689 to the splitting question indicates, that gets really insane/unmaintainable in these pathological cases where there are `"` and/or `;` in the `%PATH%`.   Having read that answer, I'm now unsure whether the problem computer had directories with `"` in the name, or directories with `;` in the name that were then quoted to avoid interpretation as a path separator.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to clean up **PATH** as no directory path in this environment variable should contain ever quotes.

Here is an example batch code for your task:

```
@echo off
rem Uncomment the line below for testing with C:\PythonXX
rem already in PATH with an erroneous double quote in PATH.
rem set "PATH=C:\PythonXX;"%PATH%"

echo Path before clean up:
echo.
echo PATH=%PATH%
set "PATH=%PATH:"=%"
echo.
echo Path after clean up:
echo.
echo PATH=%PATH%
if /I "%PATH:~0,12%" NEQ "C:\PythonXX;" set "PATH=C:\PythonXX;%PATH%"
echo.
echo Path modified:
echo.
echo PATH=%PATH%
echo.
pause
```

See the answer on [set environment variables with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and the other answers referenced there why `set "variable=value"` should be used even if the value to assign to a variable contains 1 or more quotes itself.

Comment: See also [How to search and replace a string in environment variable PATH?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24650324/3074564) It is about how to replace an existing Python path by another Python path in system __PATH__ which could be extended for your task requirements.

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary that the path contains quotes. Ex. `"C:\Music ; Audio"` contains a semicolon in the directory name. So the PATH contains `PATH=C:\windows\system32;"C:\Music ; Audio"`

Comment: Yes, that's right. This exception exists. Directory paths with a semicolon inside should be simply not allowed in my opinion as there is really never a reason to have a semicolon in a directory name at all. However, an odd number of quotes in __PATH__ requires that either a human makes this correction or a script tries to find out where missing quote should be inserted in __PATH__ by verifying which directories in __PATH__ really exist. Removing one of the quotes in `var` example in [your pretty print/split the path answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/3074564) demonstrates that issue.

Comment: Hmm, I agree that it *shouldnt* be there, in any sane world, but I'd like to work with the fact that it unfortunately *is*. Who knows, maybe some vital binary is in one if the pathologically-named dirs?  I had thought about the substring method—unfortunately the dir I'm promoting to the start of the path might not always have exactly 11 chars (`c:\PythonXX` was just an example) so the hard coded 12 is a problem. I looked for methods of finding the length of a string in batch and they're pretty horrible—the whole solution just seemed to be getting hairier and hairier.

Comment: @jez Take a look on batch function [strLen](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#strLen) if you need to get the length of a string of a variable.