# How do I add a directory to User Environment Variables (PATH) without causing duplicates?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up a script that will install python automatically, and I'm stuck on setting up the user path. I have only a vague clue about what I'm doing here so please excuse me if I'm using any terms incorrectly.

I'm trying to set the environment variables using `setx path "%PATH%;%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310"\` but I've run into several issues.
I finally have this command not failing because of 'multiple default arguments' or something but now when trying to set `PATH`, I get duplicate entries.

If originally `%PATH%` gave me `'\path1;\path2`', and I run `setx path "%PATH%;\path3"`, `%PATH%` outputs `'\path1;\path2;\path1;\path2;\path3'`,
when I expected to have `'\path1;\path2;\path3'`

As per what I've been reading from other answers, I think `%PATH%` gives you the combined SYSTEM and USER paths, but `setx path` modifies the USER path only. So everytime I run `setx path` I'm adding the system variables again.

**I just want to add my python.exe location to the user path variable in a .bat script without this duplicating issue**. Does anyone have a working solution?

Comment: See for example [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) or [How to search and replace a string in environment variable PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650324/3074564) or [Adding the current directory to Windows path permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080452/3074564).

Comment: But if you need to add the *Python* path only on your PC manually to __user__ environment variable, do not use a Windows Command Prompt and the command __SETX__ at all. Click on the Windows __Start__ button and type on the keyboard __environment__ and Windows offers in language of Windows the items __Edit environment variables for your account__ and __Edit the system environment variables__. Click on the first item for __user__ environment variables and the window __Environment Variables__ opens with the upper pane listing the __user__ environment variables. Double click on __Path__ to edit.

Comment: The path to add to the __user__ environment variable `Path` is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310` exactly as written here. Press twice the button __OK__ and best restart Windows to get the `Path` modification active for all running processes started with your user account. Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "python=%%USERPROFILE%%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"
ECHO %path%>u:\pp.txt


FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%u IN ('reg query HKCU\Environment') DO IF "%%u"=="Path" (
FIND /v "%python%" "u:\pp.txt" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 ECHO CHANGE path
 ECHO SETX PATH "%%w;%python%"
 )
)

DEL u:\pp.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a path that I have installed as `python`. Note that the `%` need to be doubled.

Write the current path to a tempfile (`u:\pp.txt` is simply on a RAMDRIVE for me)

Read the environment data from the registry, tokenise and select for the first item in `%%u` being `Path`. Its value will be in `%%w`.

See whether the "python path" is already in the path; if not, `errorlevel` will be `1` so execute the `setx`.

- I merely `echo`ed the `setx` as I'm not going to change the registry. If the command `echo`ed appears correct, remove the `echo` to actually execute the `setx`.

It may be an idea to also `set` the `path` in the current environment, as `setx` changes the variable's value for *future* instances, not for the current one.

===== Revision ==== in the light of comments:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "python=%%USERPROFILE%%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"
ECHO %path%>u:\pp.txt


FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%u IN ('reg query HKCU\Environment') DO IF /i "%%u"=="Path" (
 FIND /v "%python%" "u:\pp.txt" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET "xpath=%%w;%python%"
  SET "xpath=!xpath:~159!"
  IF DEFINED xpath (ECHO PATH too long) ELSE (
   ECHO CHANGE path
   ECHO SETX %%u "%%w;%python%"
  )
  ENDLOCAL
 )
)

DEL u:\pp*.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Fixes:

1. Comparison in `for ...%%u` made case-insensitive.
2. Length of resultant user-path variable checked. I used a value of 159 for testing, 1022 for real-world.
3. variable name being `setx`'d will be identical to that retrieved from the registry. (For me, it's `Path` (W11 22H2) - My editor helpfully changes any batch keyword followed by a space to upper-case)

Comment: __Note 1:__ The truncation is done after 1024 characters by __SETX__. So it is possible to use `SET "xpath=!xpath:~1024!"` as I verified explicitly. __Note 2:__ The batch file does not create the __user__ environment variable `Path` on not existing at all as in this case the __IF__ condition is never true. __Note 3:__ Enabled delayed expansion cause wrong behavior and `Path` value corruption on __user__ `Path` already existing and containing by chance a path with an exclamation mark. __Note 4:__ The script does not check if existing `Path` value ends already with a semicolon.